# AWS-SDK IAM credentials loading at global level

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-sdk

I use AWS-SDK a lot in my projects. And I find it time consuming to Load the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials) or to copy-paste credentials in all the required places.

Just wondering if there is a way to configure it at global level so that I don't have to include them everywhere in my node js code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by time-consuming. Do you mean runtime or development time?

All SDKs, by default, will auto-load credentials based on a specific hierarchy of credentials providers, including `~/.aws/credentials`. You typically do not need to explicitly load credentials if you are using one of these supported mechanisms.

For example, boto3 (the Python SDK) loads them, in order, from:

1. Passing credentials when creating a Client object
2. Passing credentials when creating a Session object
3. Environment variables
4. Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)
5. AWS config file (~/.aws/config)
6. Assume Role provider
7. Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg and ~/.boto)
8. Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured

Typically, if you are running an app on a developer machine, you might use #4 and #5. If your app is running on AWS infrastructure (like EC2, ECS, or Lambda), then you would use #8. Neither requires any explicit code to be written to load credentials.